# Filamentphp multiple panels

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I need help with sharing the User resource between **Admin** and **Owner** in a panel, without duplicating code or resource. I have created separate panels for each role (Admin `App\Filament\Resource\Admin` and `Owner App\Filament\Resource\Owner`), but I'm struggling with the User resource as both the `admin` and `owner` can access it.

I'm working on an admin panel that has separate logins for `Admin` and `Owner` users, and each user has different permissions. I've been told that policies can help implement this, ensuring role-based access control. Thank you.

Comment: you can try and use spatie role and permission package. Create 3 different roles (admin, owner and user) and create permission per entity/model (if post is your entity/model then post-list, post-create, post-store. post-edit, post-update, post-delete if you are using resource controller) then sync these permissions to which role that can manipulate them. Use __construct to filter which user with role/permission can access the controller.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Thank you. That is what I have exactly done. But the problem is not that  I have created two separate panels; one for the admin and the other for the writer. When I create a resource, I have to choose which panel it belongs to. However, what if I need the same resource to be available in both the admin and writer panels? Creating the same resource twice in both panels works, but it leads to a lot of code repetition and is not ideal.

Comment: then just use the same panel. If data used in the panel is the same, then there should be no problem. It would be better if you can provide the controller on your admin and writer so that we can visualize what you wish to accomplish instead of us guessing what you want to display. Also make sure it is not an image and only display basic info.